# RecyclerView that shows grouped items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can I create a horizontal RecyclerView in which the elements are grouped? Each group should have a group name that can be seen directly above the first element of a group and also scrolls with it.
I've done it so far, that an element in the RecyclerView is a complete group with one view, and in this view exists a linear layout with the elements of the group. The problem is that the elements themselves are not recycled, but are always recreated when a group is created.

Is there perhaps a better way to get the name of a group above the first group element and still recycle the views of the individual elements?

[image: RecyclerView with grpous]

Comment: Have any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Create the hashMap with key as group name and value as itemList as shown below

```
HashMap<String,List<Object>> hashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
List<Object> groupOneItems = new ArrayList<>();
groupOneItems.add("Item");
groupOneItems.add("Item");
groupOneItems.add("Item");
groupOneItems.add("Item");
List<Object> groupTwoItems = new ArrayList<>();
groupTwoItems.add("Item");
groupTwoItems.add("Item");
groupTwoItems.add("Item");
groupTwoItems.add("Item");
groupTwoItems.add("Item");
hashMap.put("Group1", groupOneItems);
hashMap.put("Group1", groupTwoItems);
```

Now pass the hashmap to the RecylerView Adapter

- For every hashMap data, show key as group name for first item and show the child items as list (You can use same view or create separate views for first item and next items)

Answer (score -1):

You can use expandable recyclerview for the implementation see [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view)